# What is this light-colored plant?

Tags: identification

Is anybody able to identify this plant? I'm trying to determine whether it is possible to trim this plant down so it isn't flopping over and generally make it look more attractive.

I'm located in Virginia, if that helps.
[image: Unidentified plant]
[image: Unidentified plant]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like *Stachys byzantina*. More information [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stachys_byzantina).